# Cloning a git repo succeeds with the command line, but fails with a git GUI client (e.g. SourceTree)

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I've set up a `git` user on a Mac OSX 10.7 system. In the git user's root, I've created a `repositories`  folder and initialized a bare git repo named `test`.

So far so good. Now, I clone the repo from a PC on the same network as the Mac with

```
git clone git@mac:repositories/test.git
```

This succeeds. I can then, push and pull from this repo. All looks good.

But, when trying to do the same thing with Atlassian SourceTree - a GUI git client - **this fails**:

```
This is not a valid source path / URL
```

[image: Atlassian SourceTree]

**Anyone an idea what I might be doing wrong?**

Comment: Try prefacing your path with ssh:// and see if that works?

Comment: @Vic - I tried, but it didn't fix it I'm afraid.

Comment: Also is there a typo no : in the Source URL in the GUI

Comment: Crazy thought-- what if you tried the IP address of the mac? Clearly you have network access and that works for you. I'm just wondering if SourceTree isn't being smart here.

Comment: @Vic - Tried as well, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not need a user name so the "Source Path/URL" entry is just the path `repositories/test.git` You would see this by hitting the button to the right which gives an open file dialog.

A URL might work but that would be of a form protocol::user@address/path and you would have to have a server running on the machine to respond to the request (in this case a git or http server)

Comment: I need to access the repo with a ssh login. So, to connect to the Mac, I need to git@mac. I can't directly enter the path `repositories/test.git`

Comment: You are not giving the machine name in URL see @Vi's suggestion ie yo need a : to separate out he machine name and possible the protocol and the //

Comment: The text in the GUI is git@macrepositories/test.git which is not what you have on the command line which is git@mac:repositories/test.git

Comment: I see the colon in the gui text. Must be really small on your screen.

Comment: Yes it is. :) It's maybe hard to see, but it really says `mac:repositories`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look for the Port in your source Path/URL.
I corrected mine by adding port something like this.. xxxxxxxx.com:YYYY/xxxxx

where xxx... is the usual source Path and YYYY is the Port Number.